# jQuery sortable placeholder horizontal divs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make placeholder on jQuery sortable. I got this code

```
$('#list').sortable({
    placeholder: "testclass",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true
});
<div id="list">
    <div class="item">First</div>
    <div class="item">Second</div>
    <div class="item">Third</div>
</div>
.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.testclass {
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/EUVrK/81/)

But it doesn't seems to work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the placeholder inline-block

```
.testclass {
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: inherited;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L4w2h/)